# Isotope: Change thumbnails to Variable Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm new to **JavaScript** and also to using **Isotope**. I've created a basic grid using the demo relayout code:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html

Where do I need to tweak the code so that the default layout shows the images in toggle variable size state.

I do not need that toggle button. Just need the page to already display the grid in variable size layout.

Please guide~!!

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

After the filtering options, but before the content starts, you need to insert "variable-sizes" as a class of the id "container". At least, that worked for me! :)

```
...
</section> <!-- #options -->
<div id="container" class="variable-sizes clickable clearfix">    
    <div class="element alkaline-earth metal" data-symbol="Mg" data-category="alkaline-earth">
...
```